# Why is it that when using "git bash" in windows it does not appear the same as when opening "wsl Ubuntu" in windows as well?

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-bash, wsl-2

I just advanced a project, I did `git add` and then `git commit` to the advances, all through **Git bash**, I check with `git status` and it seemed clean. But when entering my files through **wsl Ubuntu** on windows10, I did not see the commits made, not even the "(master)" next to the path, and when I put `git status` everything was in red (Untracked).

I have the impression that it is 2 different machines in one and that is why you did not register it, but I would like to confirm it. And also before connecting it with GitHub I would like to know that you recommend me to use: the **Git bash console** or **Ubuntu wsl on windows10? Thanks.

[it look this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Kve.png)

Comment: Ubuntu wsl or cywgin (from redhat)

Comment: Git for windows/git bash treats line endings differently than git under wsl.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before when accessing a repo in VSCode that I was modifying via WSL's `git`.  Unfortunately, I can't remember the exact details, and I can't reproduce it now.

There are two things I remember that have caused problems in this area:

- Case sensitivity issues:  I believe I saw the issue in the Microsoft WSL2 Linux kernel Github repo, and it was something like [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/git-is-casesensitive-and-your-filesystem-may-not-be-weird-folder-merging-on-windows).  That doesn't quite sound like what you are seeing, though, since all your changes were originally done under Windows git.  But it's something to consider - Is there any commit that could have caused a case-sensitivity conflict?  Also worth reading is this [Microsoft blog on the topic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/#per-directory-case-sensitivity-in-wsl) (and additional WSL options for dealing with case-sensitivity interop with Windows drives).
- Sometimes permission issues can surface when attempting to use WSL/Linux `git` on your Windows drive.  These can usually be resolved by creating (or editing, if it exists) a `/etc/wsl.conf` file with the following contents:

  ```
  [automount]
  options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
  ```

  The `metadata` option allows WSL to Linux-level permissions on files/directories on your Windows drive.  The `fmask`/`umask` determine the default Linux permission set of files/directories on your Windows drive.

Neither of these *quite* sound like your problem, but they are worth checking out.